# How to navigate from master page to detail page view using routing mechanism?

Tags: sapui5

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "RoutNav/model/models"
], function (UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("RoutNav.Component", {
        metadata: {
            manifest: "json",
            rootView: "RoutNav.view.View1",

            routes: [
                {
                    pattern: "",
                    name: "Master",
                    view: "Master",
                    targetAggregation: "masterPages",
                    targetControl: "idAppControl",
                    subroutes: [
                        {
                            pattern: "tab:",
                            name: "Detail",
                            view: "Detail"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function () {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried this, in `master.view.xml` page I have just given a title.  It's not working.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking about. The code you have added doesn't contain any navigation. Could you add a working example like a JSFiddle or Plunker to show your code?

Answer (score 0):

**you missing config code**

```js
 routing : {
      config : {
        routerClass : Application_Name.MyRouter,
        viewType : "XML",
        viewPath : "Application_Name.view",
        targetAggregation : "detailPages",
        transition: "slide",
        clearTarget : false
      },
      routes : [
        {
            pattern : "",
            name : "Master",
            view : "Master",
            targetAggregation : "masterPages",
            targetControl : "idAppControl",
            subroutes : [
                {
                    pattern : "tab:",
                    name : "Detail",
                    view : "Detail"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: hi hirse,actually my requirement is that i should create list or buttons in master page xml view  when i click on the button it should navigate to detail page using routing mechanism in sapui5,can you please show some code

Comment: hi i have tried this even master detail is not working am getting empty blank page,could anyone please share some example to navigate from master page xml view to detail page xml view using routing in sapui5

Answer (score 0):

### Steps to navigate master to detail..using JSON

1. Master.view.xml

```html
<List id="list" growing="true" mode="SingleSelectMaster"
    growingThreshold="100" growingScrollToLoad="true" select="onSelect"
    noDataText="No Data">
</List>
```

2. Master.controller.js

```js
    navBack: function(){
  var oRouter = new sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.myNavBack("S1");
 },
 onInit: function(){
  this.data = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("Model/data.json");
  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(this.data);
  
  var list = this.getView().byId("list");
  list.bindItems("/employees", new sap.m.StandardListItem({
   title: "{fname}"
  }));
  list.setModel(this.data);
 },
 onSelect: function(evt){
  var index = evt.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext().getPath();
  index.charAt(index.length-1)-2;
  
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.navTo("Detail", {
   key : evt.getParameter("listItem").getTitle()   
  });
 }
```

3. Detail.view.xml

```html
<Table onSelect="onpress" id="table" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
   <headerToolbar>
  <Toolbar>
   <Title level="H2" text="Personal Details" />
   <ToolbarSpacer />
   <Button press="onTableSettings" icon="sap-icon://drop-down-list" />
  </Toolbar>
 </headerToolbar>
  <columns>
   <Column>
    <Text text="Last_Name" key="name"/>
   </Column>
   <Column>
    <Text text="Mobile" />
   </Column>
   <Column>
       <Text text="Age" key="Age" />
   </Column>
  </columns>
 </Table>
```

3. Detail.controller.js

```js
onInit : function() {
  this.getRouter().attachRoutePatternMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);

 },

 onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
  // debugger;
  this.data = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("Model/data.json");
  this.getView().setModel(this.data);

  var dataKey = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").key;
 
  this.getView().getModel().attachRequestCompleted(function() {
   var data2 = this.getView().getModel().getData().employees;
   var otable = this.getView().byId("table");

   for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
    if (data2[i].fname === dataKey) {
     otable.bindItems("/employees", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      cells : [ new sap.m.Text({
       text : "{lname}",
      }), new sap.m.Text({
       text : "{mobile}"
      }), new sap.m.Text({
       text : "{age}"
      }) ]
     }));
    }
    otable.setModel(this.data);
   }
  }, this);

 },
 getRouter : function() {
  return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
 },
```

5. Component.js

```js
 routing : {
      config : {
        routerClass : Application_Name.MyRouter,
        viewType : "XML",
        viewPath : "Application_Name.view",
        targetAggregation : "detailPages",
        transition: "slide",
        clearTarget : false
      },
      routes : [
        {
          pattern : "",
          name : "main",
          view : "Master",
          targetAggregation : "masterPages",
          targetControl : "idAppControl",
           subroutes : [
                        {
                      pattern:"Detail/{key}",
                name: "Detail",
                view: "Detail",
                targetAggregation: "detailPages",
                     }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

6. MyRouter.js

*Just find and replace you Application_Name in MyRouter.js file*

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.Router");
jQuery.sap.declare("Application_Name.MyRouter");

sap.ui.core.routing.Router.extend("Application_Name.MyRouter", {

 constructor : function() {
  sap.ui.core.routing.Router.apply(this, arguments);
  this._oRouteMatchedHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(this);
 },

 myNavBack : function(sRoute, mData) {
  var oHistory = sap.ui.core.routing.History.getInstance();
  var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

  //The history contains a previous entry
  if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
   window.history.go(-1);
  } else {
   var bReplace = true; // otherwise we go backwards with a forward history
   this.navTo(sRoute, mData, bReplace);
  }
 },
 myNavToWithoutHash : function (oOptions) {
  var oSplitApp = this._findSplitApp(oOptions.currentView);

  // Load view, add it to the page aggregation, and navigate to it
  var oView = this.getView(oOptions.targetViewName, oOptions.targetViewType);
  oSplitApp.addPage(oView, oOptions.isMaster);
  oSplitApp.to(oView.getId(), oOptions.transition || "show", oOptions.data);
 },

 backWithoutHash : function (oCurrentView, bIsMaster) {
  var sBackMethod = bIsMaster ? "backMaster" : "backDetail";
  this._findSplitApp(oCurrentView)[sBackMethod]();
 },

 destroy : function() {
  sap.ui.core.routing.Router.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
  this._oRouteMatchedHandler.destroy();
 },

 _findSplitApp : function(oControl) {
  var sAncestorControlName = "idAppControl";

  if (oControl instanceof sap.ui.core.mvc.View && oControl.byId(sAncestorControlName)) {
   return oControl.byId(sAncestorControlName);
  }

  return oControl.getParent() ? this._findSplitApp(oControl.getParent(), sAncestorControlName) : null;
 }

});
```

**Don't forget to add MyRouter.js file**

Comment: can you please tell what code should we add in MyRouter.js??

Comment: OK..Just find and replace your Application_Name

Comment: hi please provide me an simple example navigating from master page xml view to detail page xml view using routing by creating simple buttons,as am new to sap

Comment: hi i just need two buttons in master page and onclicking data should be displayed in detail,simple example,i have tried the above one ,am unable to get the output

Comment: cannot read property 'interpolate' of undefined am getting this error in master pages buttons are displayed but once i click tat am getting that error

Comment: check ur **App.view.xml** spliteContainer Id & **component.js** targetControl Id should be same.

Comment: YA I HAVE GIVEN THE SAME ID EVERYWHERE

Answer (score 0):

```
"routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewPath": "mc7prod.view",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "clearTarget": "false"
     },
     "routes": [
     {
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "Index",
        "view": "Index",
        "targetControl": "appId"
     },
     {
        "pattern": "split",
        "name": "AppMasterDetail",
        "view": "AppMasterDetail",
        "targetControl": "appId",
        "subroutes": [
            {
                "pattern": "master/{entity}",
                "name": "master",
                "view": "TS_Master",
                "targetAggregation": "masterPages",
                "preservePageInSpplitContainer": true,
                "targetControl": "idAppMaDeControl",
                "subroutes": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "detail/{entity}",
                        "name": "detail",
                        "view": "TS_Detail",
                        "targetAggregation": "detailPages"
                    }
                ]}]
        },
```

Comment: this.getRouter().navTo("master",{entity : "Detail"});

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.